# Textbox is not wrapping the words in xaml - windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make my textbox to be able to wrap the word. Which means that when the sentences are reaching the the end of the textbox, it should go to the next line but it didnt go to the next line even i have stated the statement textbox wrapping. Below is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:DatePicker Name="dateData"  
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Width="456"
                            Background="DarkBlue" 
                            ValueStringFormat="{}{0:D}"
                            Foreground="White"
                            BorderBrush="DarkBlue" />

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Text="Title" Margin="18,0,0,0"  />

        <TextBox x:Name="title"  
                 Text="Add New Title"
                 FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"     
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                 BorderBrush="Silver" />

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Description" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Margin="18,0,0,0"  />

        <TextBox  x:Name="Desc" 
                  Text="Add New Description"
                  TextWrapping="Wrap"
                  FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"  
                  Height="125" 
                  BorderBrush="Silver" />

        <CheckBox Name="cBox" 
                  Checked="cBox_Checked" 
                  Content="Reminder" 
                  Unchecked="cBox_Unchecked"  />

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Name="textRDate"
                   Text="Reminder Date" 
                   Margin="18,0,0,0" 
                   Visibility="Collapsed"   />

        <toolkit:DatePicker Name="rrDate" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Width="456"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"    />

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Name="TextTDate"
                   Text="Reminder Time" 
                   Margin="18,0,0,0" 
                   Visibility="Collapsed"   />

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Name="hiddenTime"
                   Margin="18,0,0,0" 
                   Visibility="Collapsed"  />

        <toolkit:TimePicker  Name="rrTime" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             Width="456"
                             Visibility="Collapsed"   />

        <TextBlock x:Name="Id"  Height="72" Margin="0,373,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons,

Over-complicated layout architecture and the way your objects are positioning each other.

Solutions:

(i) Try removing Vetical Alignment on TextBlock

(ii) Trim your string when you are binding to the Textblock

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works now. I actually have that vertical alignment which made it went vertically. Careless mistake. Now it works :)